# Laravel 4, Sentry 2 and user permissions

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am about to begin building a system that will require a set questions to be selected and saved as a checklist document for distribution to an arbitrary set of users.

I am intending to use Laravel 4 as my framework and Sentry 2 to handle permissions.

**My question is:**

If I use a user with, lets say, *Admin* level access to create a check list and I have, say 100, *Inspector* level users, can I restrict access to a single checklists for every individual users using Sentry? I ideally want to allow a user to have access to a single checklist (collection of checks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create separate groups for your checklists:

```
// Create the group
$group = Sentry::createGroup(array(
    'name'        => 'Administrators',
    'permissions' => array(
        'checklists.admin' => 1,
        'checklists.view' => 1,
    ),
));

// Create the group
$group = Sentry::createGroup(array(
    'name'        => 'checklists.view.101',
    'permissions' => array(
        'checklists.view.101' => 1,
    ),
));
```

Add your user to a checklist group:

```
$user = Sentry::getUser()->addGroup( Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findByName('Checklist101') );
```

And check if it has access to it:

```
return $user->hasAnyAccess(['checklists.view', 'checklists.view.101'])
```

In this case, if your user is administrator, it will also be able to view it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this would not work if check lists are created dynamically unless every time I create a list, I create a group especially for that list and assign users to the new group. Would this not end up polluting the user groups table? Personally, I am now thinking along the lines of separating user/check list to a lookup table listing the check list ID and the allowed user ID's.

Comment: Having a way to separate real groups from lists groups, what's the problem of "polluting" your groups tables? Imo it's better than just creating something completely different to handle something that should be handled by your main authorization class.

Comment: Fair enough, I can see your point there. I see there are user specific permissions I could use too. Once again, my thanks.